# Add column with substring of other column in SQL (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I feel like this should be simple but I'm relatively unskilled in SQL and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm used to wrangling data in python (pandas) or Spark (usually pyspark) and this would be a one-liner in either of those. Specifically, I'm using Snowflake SQL, but I think this is probably relevant to a lot of flavors of SQL.

Essentially I just want to trim the first character off of a specific column. More generally, what I'm trying to do is replace a column with a substring of the same column. I would even settle for creating a new column that's a substring of an existing column. I can't figure out how to do any of these things.

On obvious solution would be to create a temporary table with something like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_sub AS 
SELECT id_col, substr(id_col, 2, 10) AS id_col_sub FROM table1
```

and then join it back and write a new table

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT 
b.id_col_sub as id_col,
a.some_col1, a.some_col2, ...
FROM table1 a
JOIN tmp_sub b
ON a.id_col = b.id_col
```

My tables have roughly a billion rows though and this feels extremely inefficient. Maybe I'm wrong? Maybe this is just the right way to do it? I guess I could replace the `CREATE TABLE table2 AS...` to `INSERT OVERWRITE INTO table1 ...` and at least that wouldn't store an extra copy of the whole thing.

Any thoughts and ideas are most welcome. I come at this humbly from the perspective of someone who is baffled by a language that so many people seem to have mastery over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact syntax/functions in Snowflake but generally speaking there's a few different ways of achieving this.
I guess the general approach that would work universally is using the SUBSTRING function that's available in any database.

Assuming you have a table called Table1 with the following data:

```
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
  Code  | Desc
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
 0001   | 1First Character Will be Removed
 0002   | xCharacter to be Removed
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
```

The SQL code to remove the first character would be:

```
select SUBSTRING(Desc,2,len(desc)) from Table1
```

Please note that the **"SUBSTRING"** function may vary according to different databases. In Oracle for example the function is **"SUBSTR"**. You just need to find the Snowflake correspondent.

Another approach that would work at least in SQLServer and MySQL would be using the **"RIGHT"** function

```
select RIGHT(Desc,len(Desc) - 1) from Table1
```

Based on your question I assume you actually want to update the actual data within the table. In that case you can use the same function above in an update statement.

```
update Table1 set Desc = SUBSTRING(Desc,2,len(desc))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. `SET`
Thank you very much.

Comment: This is pretty great! Thank you for your help, if you are interested the Snowflake Community has  Select Star program that adds points to your profile if you are a register Snowflake user, check out the page and sign up if you are interested: https://community.snowflake.com/s/selectstar

Answer (score 1):

You didn't try this?

```
UPDATE tableX
   SET columnY = substr(columnY, 2, 10 ) ;
```

-Paul-

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify the length, as is evidenced from the following simple test harness:

`SELECT $1
      ,SUBSTR($1, 2)
      ,RIGHT($1, -2)
  FROM VALUES
         ('abcde')
        ,('bcd')
        ,('cdef')
        ,('defghi')
        ,('e')
        ,('fg')
        ,('')
;`

Both expressions here - **SUBSTR(<col>, 2)** and **RIGHT(<col>, -2)** - effectively remove the first character of the <col> column value.

As for the strategy of using UPDATE versus INSERT OVERWRITE, I do not believe that there will be any difference in performance or outcome, so I might opt for the UPDATE since it is simpler. So, in conclusion, I would use:

`UPDATE tableX
   SET columnY = SUBSTR(columnY, 2)
;`